# Favicon not working in Internet Explorer (any verison)

Tags: html, internet-explorer, favicon

[My site](http://www.sfmgroupsales.com/).

I tried numerous things on Stack Overflow and various forums but can't seem to get this working. It works in all other browsers, but not IE (any version) :( HELP! I'm pulling my hair out over this one!

Comment: There are million sites with favicon working in IE. Open one and see their markup.

Comment: Your [favicon image file](http://www.sfmgroupsales.com/favicon.ico) simply does not exist, it returns 404. No idea how it works in "other browsers" - it won't work in any. My best guess is that you used to have such file then removed it at some point. Some of your browsers cached the icon, some did not.

Comment: Yea it does 404 now as I have changed the cod & file type as per the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Yes as Michal said, you can easily find it:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="http://www.yoursite.com/images/favicon.png">
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, I have already tried copying from another site that I can see the Favicon working, hoever, I still cannot get that to work. I have used the code you mentioned and obviously changed the path to match mine, but it still doesn't work in IE (I was previously using .ico but I can see that your example is using a .png so I have changed it. Thanks

Comment: Yeah it worked for me everywhere. Don't know what must be wrong. Try removing the type and is it inside the '<head>' tag ?

Comment: It strange :/ Ive never really had this trouble before. I have removed the type and yes, it is the head tag. :/

Comment: Hmm, strange but you may try few things just to be sure form all angles. Try different combinations like remove type use only "icon" instead of shortcut icon, put your image inside a folder instead of your site root directory. And lastly remove all cache and wait for may be 15-20 minutes. Good luck.